# Core Plot 1.1: Compile error when compiling Core Plot Examples

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-plot

When trying to compile the following CorePlot 1.1 examples in Xcode 4.6, I get an compiler error.

- `DatePlot`
- `CPTTestApp - iPad`

Compiler error in `CPTUtilities.m`: `Operand of ? changes signedness: 'int' to 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')`

```
NSRange CPTExpandedRange(NSRange range, NSInteger expandBy)
{
    NSUInteger loc = MAX(0, (NSInteger)range.location - expandBy);
    NSUInteger lowerExpsion = range.location - loc; // Here is the error
    NSUInteger length = (NSUInteger)( (NSInteger)(range.length + lowerExpansion) + expandBy);

    return NSMakeRange(loc, length);
}
```

Comment: Show how you call CPTExpandedRange function.

Comment: I am just opening the sample file and compiling it (for Mac OSX 64 bit). Can you compile the sample files of Core Plot 1.1?

Comment: This sounds like the new LLVM version in the Xcode 4.6 beta might be presenting more strict warnings here. Either drop back to the current stable Xcode 4.5 version, or report this as a bug on the Core Plot mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss

Comment: I tried to file a bug report on your Google Groups site, but received an error from Google Groups: `There was an error posting the message to the group. Please try again later`. It seems that Google Groups has some bugs too... :-) Would it be possible that you report this as a Core Plot bug please?

Comment: The actual issues tracker is here: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list , but the Google Groups mailing list is just that, a mailing list. You can simply send an email to it. I haven't been active with this project for over a year.

Comment: Thank you for the issues tracker URL, Brad! I have filed a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue (issue #501) has now been fixed by the Core Plot team:

[Issue 501 fixed](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=501&can=1&sort=-id)

Comment: compiled today with the latest (1.1) and still incurring the issue

Comment: had to download via hg clone NOT the downloads section 1.1 version

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the answer is placed there, simply only changes the function, I left a copy that how is the right code:

```
    NSRange CPTExpandedRange(NSRange range, NSInteger expandBy)

//NSUInteger loc            = MAX(0, (NSInteger)range.location - expandBy);
//NSUInteger lowerExpansion = range.location - loc;
//NSUInteger length         = (NSUInteger)( (NSInteger)(range.length + lowerExpansion) + expandBy );

NSInteger loc            = MAX(0, (NSInteger)range.location - expandBy);
NSInteger lowerExpansion = (NSInteger)range.location - loc;
NSInteger length         = MAX(0, (NSInteger)range.length + lowerExpansion + expandBy);

//return NSMakeRange(loc, length);
return NSMakeRange( (NSUInteger)loc, (NSUInteger)length );
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but i cannot found how is fixed this compiler error. I'm on the same situation as Alex.
Trying to compile the examples and get the same error.
Running on XCode 4.6 and Mountain Lion.  CorePlot 1.1 and tried targets 5.1,6.0 and 6.1

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you download the last source code release from the repository? The "normal" Core Plot 1.1 download contains the error. You have to download the last source code release manually.

Comment: @AlexR: Here's what they have changed: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/diff?spec=svn68d8fa3ce8e0a698d6175fe6f30efb731de3e757&name=68d8fa3ce8e0&r=68d8fa3ce8e0a698d6175fe6f30efb731de3e757&format=side&path=/framework/Source/CPTUtilities.m